# Angular 6 how to correctly utilize focusout but prevent it's execution when clicking itself

Tags: angular, onclick, click, focusout

I have a demo of my issue on a stackblitz that you can try out : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-u7erfg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

My goal is to have a div who's click is caught to prevent focusout execution (I can't prevent focusout from firering but I can place an if within the method called by focusout and check my condition, whatever it is, in there).

Or, aternatively, is there another method that could accomplish similar, if better, results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-8dxj2s?file=app/app.component.ts)

Basically it uses the mousedown to prevent the default focusout event. And when a file has been chosen, it closes the green square:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  opened = false;
  dostuff = false;

  toggle(){
    this.opened = !this.opened
    if(!this.opened) this.dostuff = false;
  }


  mouseInside(event){
    this.dostuff = true;
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  focusOut(){
    if (!this.dostuff) {
      this.opened = false;
    }
  }

  onFileChange(event) {
    this.opened = false;
    this.dostuff = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe I'm missing something but your setup wouldn't ever trigger `focusOut()`, normally when you click on the blue div on the right, the green div on the left should become red (closed state). I added `this.opened = false; console.log('hello');` inside the if and still nothing, not even in the console.

Comment: @tatsu my bad indeed, I misinterpreted the opened and dostuff variables. Ive posted a new stakcblitz and updated my answer

Comment: ok : the other problem this suffers from as compared to my approach is that it only works once.

Comment: @tatsu ah yes, only when you cancel the file input though, you should do something about that :). Anyways, the important thing is to use the mousedown in combination with preventDefault. The rest is up to you

Comment: you're right. I had assumed it would do the same with file associate. I'm going to experiment with this, perhaps it solves my issue.

Comment: yeah I like this solution. I had other use cases for focusouts  required in my app that were simpler and for which an even simpler version of this worked perfectly, thanks!